# How to serialize Pen in C#?

Tags: c#, serialization, system.drawing

I have a Shape class wich contains

```
public Pen outlinePen;
```

What I try to do is to serialize List of Shape, but all I have is`Type`

> 'System.Drawing.Pen' in Assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as
>   serializable.

If i mark this field as `[field: NonSerialized()]` then I can't use my loaded objects, because outlinePen is null.

Are there any other ways to serialize System.Drawing.Pen?

Comment: If you want to serialize it, why mark it as `NonSerializable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should serialize only the data you interested in . `Pen` is a graphic object , so even if it would be possible, imo, it's not a good idea to store it.

For example in your case you can store `PenColor`, `PenWidth` and `PenStyle` like a `PenDataObject`, which is kind of `Pen` lighweght object specially created to store `Pen` data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking about it but I tried to avoid it, because I use pen inside the class to draw it. Now I've done as you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

`Pen` is internally marked as non-serializable by .NET and it's sealed so you can't subclass and serialize it either. If you need to serialize graphics, you can look into the [Metafile class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbk7dbtb.aspx) which is specifically designed to store graphics and drawing objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend a different approach involving the execution of some logic when the parent object is deserialized.

```
[NonSerialized]
private Pen _penToUse;

[OnDeserialized()]
internal void Reinitialize(StreamingContext context)
{
    SwitchPen(); //now we can restore the Pen, the easy way would be 
                 //to store it in a static class in the domain
}
```